# Why is my Regular Expression not matching?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have the following pattern:

```py
find_pattern = re.compile(r'(ga:country:\s)([a-zA-Z()\s]*)(.*users:\s)(\d+),')
```

This is how the input that should be matched looks like:

```
        ga:country: (not set),Date range:0,ga:users:60,
        ga:country: Albania,Date range:0,ga:users:7,
        ga:country: Algeria,Date range:0,ga:users:10,
        ...
        ga:country: Argentina,Date range:0,ga:users:61,
        ga:country: Armenia,Date range:0,ga:users:2,
```

And this is how the output is going to be formatted (in case it adds any value to the question):

```
        ['(not set)', 60],
        ['Albania', 7],
```

And when I run a test:

```
matches = find_pattern.finditer(self.data)
print('matches:', matches)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

No matches are found.

Hope someone is able to help.

Comment: There should be a `\s*` after `ga:` and the `\s` after `users:` should be optional like `(ga:\s*country:\s)([a-zA-Z()\s]*)(.*users:\s*)(\d+),` https://regex101.com/r/BIfgez/1

Comment: Second one nailed it. Big thanks! :-) To anyone else reading this, first \s* was because I initially made a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using 2 capturing groups instead of 4, add optional whitespace chars after `ga:` and make the whitspace chars optional after `users:`

The `.*` could also be non greedy `.*?` to get the first one in case there are more `users:` parts.

To prevent `users:` begin part of a larger word, you could make it more specific matching `:users:`

```
\bga:\s*country:\s*([a-zA-Z()\s]*),.*?:users:(\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pSNpR0/1)

**Example** with re.findall that returns the values of the capturing groups:

```
import re

regex = r"\bga:\s*country:\s*([a-zA-Z()\s]*),.*?:users:(\d+)"

s = ("ga:country: (not set),Date range:0,ga:users:60,\n"
    "ga:country: Albania,Date range:0,ga:users:7,\n"
    "ga:country: Algeria,Date range:0,ga:users:10,\n"
    "ga:country: Argentina,Date range:0,ga:users:61,\n"
    "ga:country: Armenia,Date range:0,ga:users:2,")

print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
[('(not set)', '60'), ('Albania', '7'), ('Algeria', '10'), ('Argentina', '61'), ('Armenia', '2')]
```